# how do i configure entry point of react project in MicroFrontend.jsx?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, manifest.json, micro-frontend

I have a 3 react project which are combined MicrofrontEnd application.
I am trying to switch from Webpack(react-app-rewired) to vite.

```
fetch(`${host}/manifest.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((manifest) => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.id = scriptId;
        script.crossOrigin = "";
        script.src = `${host}/${manifest['index.html'].file}`;
        script.onload = () => {
          renderMicroFrontend();
        };
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      });

    return () => {
      window[`unmount${name}`] && window[`unmount${name}`](`${name}-container`);
    };
```

how do i configure entry point of react project in MicroFrontend.jsx?

[Our source is here](https://github.com/tugsuu88/microfrontends-using-reactjs)

I am trying to configure entry point of application on Container app